# What is the induced map on stalks?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $F$ and $G$ be sheaves of sets on some topological space $X$, and let $x\in X$. People often say that each natural transformation $F\to G$ induces a map on the stalks $F_x\to G_x$, but they don't define precisely *what* that map is. Apparently it's trivial for most people, but since I am stupid I have to think about that.

Recall that the stalk of $F$ at $x$ is the colimit of all $F(U)$ where $U\ni x$.

Also, recall that by definition the colimit construction $C^J\to C$ is left adjoint to the diagonal $C\to C^J$. In particular it is itself a functor: if $F', G'\colon J\to C$, then each natural transformation $F'\to G'$ induces a map from the colimit of $F'$ to the colimit of $G'$. (*)

Now let $F\to G$ be a natural transformation between the sheaves $F$ and $G$. This induces a natural transformation between $F', G'\colon J\to C$, where $J:=\{U\in\mathrm{Open}(X)\mid U\ni x\}$, $C:=\mathrm{Set}$, and $F'$ and $G'$ are the restrictions of $F$ and $G$ to $J$. This in turn induces by (*) a map from the colimit of $F'$ to the colimit of $G'$. But the colimit of $F'$ is by definition the stalk of $F$ at $x$, similarly for $G$. Hence we get a map $F_x\to G_x$.

**Is the map I just described equal to the map people call the "canonical map" $F_x\to G_x$ induced by the natural transformation $F\to G$?**

Comment: Yes. This **is** the canonical map on stalks.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it equal to the map described in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1913700/1086520?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be a little more concrete, an element of $F_p$ is a pair $(U, f)$ where $f \in F(U)$ and where we identify two such pairs $(f, U)$ and $(g, V)$ if $f = g$ on some subset of $U \cap V$ that still contains $p$.

Given such a pair $(U, f)$ we get a section $\phi(f)$ of $G(U)$ since we have a sheaf map $\phi: F \to G$. Check that the pair $(V, \phi(f))$ is well-defined as an element of $G_p$.

Comment: What you do is give another construction of the map on stalks $F_x\to G_x$. But you don't explain why your construction of the map coincides with my construction of the map.

Comment: After all, does your construction coincide with mine?

Comment: Yes. I am just spelling out the definition of a colimit.

Comment: I am not asking about a colimit, I am asking about a map between colimits.

Comment: @user1086520 See the second paragraph for an explicit description of the map induced on the colimit. This is the same as the induced map from the definition of colimit, I am just spelling things out.